# How do you add subtitle in cardFactory bot framework sdk v4

Tags: botframework

How do make this one:

[image]

Look like this one:

[image]

The first image has the code of:

```
const dpCard = CardFactory.heroCard(
                            'Incomplete Application',
                            null,
                            CardFactory.actions([
                                {
                                    type: 'openUrl',
                                    title: 'Proceed',
                                    value: 'https://chatbot.ewbconsumerlending.com/chatdemo.html?ref=' + stepContext.values.userMain.psid
                                }
                            ])
                        );
                        await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ attachments: [dpCard] });
```

[CardFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/cardfactory?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#herocard-string--string---cardimage----string---cardaction----partial-herocard--) seems to have no subtitle property. So I wonder how can I mechanize the [subtitle](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/generic/) of FB in their buttons. (Can I use other parameter in heroCard? If so, how do I use it?) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it: I guess **other?: Partial** in CardFactory class is just an object

```
const dpCard = CardFactory.heroCard(
                            'Incomplete Application',
                            null,
                            CardFactory.actions([
                                {
                                    type: 'openUrl',
                                    title: 'Proceed',
                                    value: 'https://chatbot.ewbconsumerlending.com/chatdemo.html?ref=' + stepContext.values.userMain.psid
                                }
                            ]),
                            {
                                subtitle: 'You can continue your application by clicking the button below'
                            }
                        );
```

From code above, { subtitle: '' } is the difference and works same.